# Approximate the value of the integral with an error less than $ 10^{-3}$

Tags: calculus

Approximate the value of the integral with an error less than $ 10^{-3}$
 [Do not add the numbers in the sum!]
$$\large \int_0^1 \sin (x^2)dx$$

So this is what i have tried and am stuck from there. Any assistance highly appreciated. My problem lies in the alternating series estimation theorem.

Comment: Remember that $\sin(x^2) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2(2n+1)}}{(2n+1)!}$. You want to integrate term by term of the power series, where the limits are from $0$ to $1$. So your series should look like $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(4n+3)(2n+1)!}$. Do you remember how to estimate $R_n$, where it is the total sum $s$ minus $s_n$, sequence of partial sums?

Comment: This is a [Fresnel integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: at $x=1$, the absolute values of the terms in the sum are decreasing. Which is the first term strictly less than $10^{-3}$?

Comment: Give me a minute i compute this thanks for the hint.

Comment: Hey i found $\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{42}$ with error $< 10^{-3}$  Thanks,, i hope am right.

Comment: Indeed. You had already made it 95% of the way there.